# software to remove Hard Drive password

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Asus computer that when booted asks for hard drive password.  I do not know what happened but I didn;t put a password on it.  When I ran bios and CMOS programs they both said that the bios password was disabled so I am figuring that is not the issue.  Can someone tell me what I can do to get past the password, or if there is any software out there that will crack it?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anyone succeding. I belive the only way is to erase hdd by making exact copy of the HDD by using enterprise-level hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more things you want to check -

1. The BIOS password is not the same as a hard drive password - A hard drive password is set by going into the BIOS but the password is stored in the firmware. If you took this drive to another machine, it would be inaccessible. Check in the BIOS for the HDD password. If this was something that was accidentally set by you, you could try using passwords you may regularly use to see if you can unlock it.
2. If you can't unlock the drive, there are ways to retrieve the password - just so you know but I will not explain or outline the process.

Comment: I understand that the Bios password and the Hard drive password are not the same.  Why there is all of the sudden a password at all is one issue the other is I cant get my wife back into her computer unless I find a way to get past what ever the pw is.  Is there anyway to do that without it costing more than the computer is worth?

Comment: Chances are very low that the system set the HDD password itself, I would recommend trying the usual suspects for passwords. If someone else was fiddling with / had access to the system, now would be appropriate to give them a hard time. A simple search will show you how to unlock the HDD if you are inclined, otherwise - buy a new drive.